# itoa() and atoi() in the same printf instruction does not work properly

Tags: c

Here is a code sample where the call of `itoa(N,STR,2)` and `atoi(STR)` in the same `printf` instruction does not work properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
  int N; char STR[50];
  do
  { 
    printf("Give a number : ");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    printf("--------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Your given number is  = %d\n", N);  
    printf("N in Binary = %s\t  Binary String of N is = %d\n", itoa(N,STR,2), atoi(STR));
    printf("N in Binary = %s\n", itoa(N,STR,2));
    printf("Binary String of N is = %d \n", atoi(STR));
    printf("N in Binary = %s\t  Binary String of N is = %d\n", itoa(N,STR,2), atoi(STR));  
  }
  while(N);
  return 0;
}
```

So, what is the problem? It is expected that lines 12 and 15 give the same results, but the result was as follows :

```
Give a number : 12
--------------------------------------
Your given number is  = 12
N in Binary = 1100        Binary String of N is = 0
N in Binary = 1100
Binary String of N is = 1100
N in Binary = 1100        Binary String of N is = 1100
Give a number :
```

Comment: Tip: ditch `itoa()` and just use `snprintf()` instead. It's at least portable.

Comment: @DevNull ack, though snprintf does not support binary

Answer (score 6):

When you write

```
printf("N in Binary = %s\t  Binary String of N is = %d\n", itoa(N,STR,2), atoi(STR));
```

you seem to be assuming that the subterms of `printf` are evaluated from left to right. The C standard doesn't specify order of evaluation of function arguments. You thus have a classic case of undefined behavior.

Also -- you really should declare `main` as

```
int main(void)
```

to make it conform to recent standards.

Comment: Many Thanks but ,
Firstly, if it is as what you said it will be really a big bug in the C language since it is not noted in C manuals or books.
Secondly, I think that I usually call fuction in printf and it is the first time for me to see such confusion.

Comment: It is an important fact that compilers are free to determine the order in which function arguments are evaluated. This is one of the things that allows optimizing compilers to do their magic. As a general rule of thumb, avoid using in an expression things (such as i++) that modify variables as a side effect when those same variables are used elsewhere in the exact same expression. Don't try to guess exactly when the side effect will take place in the middle of the expression since you might guess wrong.

Comment: @LiveFreeorDieHard Since you're here to learn, please do so, and listen to this answer, because it's correct!  You can call a function inside of a call to `printf` if you want, that's not necessarily a problem, but if you call several functions, you absolutely cannot depend on them being called left-to-right.  It's true that this can be confusing, it's true that it's not always covered well in C books, and it's not surprising you didn't notice it at first.

Comment: There are many C and C++ books that don't contain the string "undefined behaviour".

Comment: Many thanks to John Coleman and Steve Summit

It's true that this can be confusing and not always covered well in C books but such confusion allows optimizing compilers to do their magic.

So, the conclusion is that it is preferred to not call functions or use identifiers that are dependent in the same call to printf or other functions.

Comment: C is a fairly old language. It is powerful, but far less user-friendly than something like Python. In my own case, I think I never quite "got" the language until I read "C Programming: A modern approach" by K.N. King

Answer (score 3):

The order in which `printf()`'s arguments get evaluated is not defined.

So you want to break this line

```
 printf("N in Binary = %s\t  Binary String of N is = %d\n", itoa(N,STR,2), atoi(STR));
```

apart into

```
 printf("N in Binary = %s\t  ", itoa(N,STR,2));
 printf("Binary String of N is = %d\n", atoi(STR));
```

---

As a side effect to what I explained above this 1st `printf()`

```
 printf("N in Binary = %s\t  Binary String of N is = %d\n", itoa(N,STR,2), atoi(STR));
```

might even invoke undefined behaviour in case this argument

```
 ... atoi(STR));
```

gets evaluated 1st, because then `STR` is used (still) uninitialised, as `itoa(N,STR,2)` had not been called yet.

Comment: Thanks, but not exactly what I mean. The problem is that line 12 doesn't give a correct result as expected.

Comment: @LiveFreeorDieHard: Propably because 1st `atoi` is called then `itoa()`. Line 15 seems to work because `STR` is already/still initialised from the previous call to `itoa()`.

Comment: To get enlightened change `char STR[50]` to be `char STR[50] = "42";` (and do not enter `42` at the prompt ...).

Comment: Thanks but it is good to see the answer it is too important because you can see this confusion even in the instruction "printf("%d %d %d \n",i++,i++,i++). of course you have to initialize i and see.

Comment: @LiveFreeorDieHard: The example in you comment is UB in any case.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I found that answers and comments of @John Coleman and @Steve Summit are very helpful.

It's true that this can be confusing and not always covered well in C books but such confusion allows optimizing compilers to do their magic.

So, the conclusion is that it is preferred to not call functions or use identifiers that are dependent in the same call to `printf` or other functions.